# Porting a Fortran project from Windows Visual Studio to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, fortran, intel

I have to compile a Fortran code with several files and dependencies that was developed in Windows using Visual Studio Intel Fortran to Linux. Is there any tool to convert the project to a Makefile, CMake or any other format?

Comment: Something like this: https://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/? No idea about its efficacy though.

Comment: You can get Intel Visual Fortran for Linux.  It is compatible: why do you need to convert?

Comment: Because there are several dependencies between the files, and this information is in the Visual Studio project. Without convertion I would have to check and order the files (around 300 files) by hand.

Comment: @Ivan did you ever get this figured out?